# How to preserve form values when sorting with an ASP.NET MVC4 WebGrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sorting, filter, webgrid

I'm building a search page in MVC4 with a filter form and a webgrid helper to display the data.  Filtering and sorting all works fine, with the exception that when I click a column to sort, it reloads the initial version of the page using the GET controller function with the sort parameters, losing the filter settings.  I would really like it to resubmit the form to the POST controller function so that the filter form is used and repopulated.  What's the best way for me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most elegant solution, but it works:

Add the model to your Session in the view:

```
Session.Add( "Model", Model );
```

Then, in the Index GET Action in your controller (or whatever the GET Action is), just check for the value and call the POST Action:

```
if ( Session[ "Model" ] != null )
    this.Index( Session[ "Model" ] as MyModel );
```

Cleanup your Session accordingly.